# If the only permalink setting is %postname% what happens in the case of old duplicates?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, duplicates

I am tempted to change my blog to be site.com/postname.

I know that for new posts Wordpress is smart enough to add a unique number to them, but what about old posts that would get updated?

I can run a database check for duplicates and manually fix them but I was wondering if this was already covered by some Wordpress magic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you have a duplicate slug for a post or taxonomy, WordPress just adds '-2' to the end of the slug.

Comment: So it doesn't matter if it's an "old" post or what your permalink settings are, WP ensures that all slugs are unique?

Comment: That's right. The same goes for tags and categories.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's covered by WP magic; and lately there's been much discussion of how bad it can be performance-wise to use %postname% alone, for example http://digwp.com/2011/06/dont-use-postname/ You might have better luck with %year%/%postname. Best of luck!